# Why does CreateProcess ignore STARTUPINFO window size values?

Tags: c#, winapi, createprocess

I am trying to use CreateProcess to start Notepad at a specific window size to avoid the flashing that occurs when it appears somewhere for a split second before I can resize it and move it.

CreateProcess starts Notepad but CreateProcess and Notepad both ignore the window dimensions in the STARTUPINFO structure. Notepad appears in the normal place at the normal size where it was last closed.

No combination of `dwFlags` that I tried worked. Notepad either does not appear at all or ignores my settings and appears in a place and size determined by the operating system.

Why is CreateProcess ignoring the values I set in STARTUPINFO? Am I missing something?

```
[TestMethod()]
  public void CreateProcessTest() {
    const uint NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x0020;
    const uint STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x0001;

    // create structures needed by CreateProcess
    var pInfo = new Kernel32.PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    var pSec = new Kernel32.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    var tSec = new Kernel32.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
    tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);

    // set the app and a file to open
    var app = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\notepad.exe";
    var arguments = @" C:\somefile.txt";

    // the started app window does not use these values
    var sInfo = new Kernel32.STARTUPINFO();
    sInfo.dwX = 800;  // desired x-y position of the window
    sInfo.dwY = 400;
    sInfo.dwXSize = 200; // desired size of the window
    sInfo.dwYSize = 400;

    // no combination of these flags that I tried makes any difference
    // Notepad always appears as normal and ignores the size settings above
    sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    sInfo.wShowWindow = (short) Win32.SW_SHOW;

    // create the process
    var result = Kernel32.CreateProcess(app, arguments,
      ref pSec, ref tSec, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
      IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfo, out pInfo);
  }
```

Comment: *For GUI processes, this is used only the first time the new process calls `CreateWindow` to create an overlapped window if the `nWidth` parameter of `CreateWindow` is `CW_USEDEFAULT`.* - what if notepad not use *CW_USEDEFAULT* ?

Comment: *Notepad appears in the normal place at the normal size **where it was last closed**.* - this say about notepad save self last window size and position and use it, but not use *CW_USEDEFAULT*

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are you saying that Notepad can do its own thing and decide for itself whether or not to use the STARTUPINFO settings (by maybe not using CW_USEDEFAULT, whatever that is)? In other words, apps can (and probably do) ignore the startupinfo settings?

Comment: of course. any app can call *CreateWindowEx* and not use *CW_USEDEFAULT* in parameters, but use another values in size and position

Comment: "avoid the flashing that occurs when it appears somewhere for a split second before I can resize it and move it"   So create it hidden, reposition it, then show it.

Comment: @Kevin "*In other words, apps can (and probably do) ignore the startupinfo settings?*" - that is exactly what happens, yes. The `STARTUPINFO` values are just a *suggestion*, but apps are free to do whatever they want.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem with the hiding a window theory is that it assumes that I own the window (which I don't). I'm just trying to start Notepad, which apparently does its own thing. Thank you to everyone who responded. I will just put up with the flash for now. :-)

Comment: Yeah, CreateProcess doesn't ignore it, the app does

Comment: @Kevin: I'm quite sure that notepad respects `wShowWindow` (this is conveniently exposed in the shortcut properties GUI so I was able to test it quickly). So you can cause it to be initially hidden.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hi Ben, I did play with combinations of the wShowWindow flag. Maybe I interpreted the hidden result as "it didn't work." I read that if a window is hidden, the process.MainWindowHandle is zero or invalid, so I could not set the size of it anyway. Does agree with your knowledge?

Comment: @Kevin: If a window is hidden (no WS_VISIBLE style) then `CreateWindow` has still returned a handle, but it may be more difficult to find it from outside the process.  In particular, the C# `MainWindowHandle` property is probably searching for a visible window.  You can still find the window handle if you know something unique about it, such as the classname (that is `lpszClassName` in `WNDCLASS` not a C# class)

Comment: @Kevin: Also, I'm not sure how you would mistake whether "start maximized" is working or not.  It's really obvious when it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa):
the **dwFlags** member of STARTUPINFO needs to add **STARTF_USEPOSITION** and **STARTF_USESIZE**.

Edited,
Store in registry directory:Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad.

iWindowPosDX
iWindowPosDY
iWindowPosX
iWindowPosY

Comment: and ? you think that after this you can overwrite arguments to *CreateWindowEx* in child process ?

Comment: @RbMb: A well-behaved application uses the position passed to it, and as this answer correctly points out, there is not actually any position being passed.

Comment: @RbMb: Also yes, it does overwrite the application-provided argument to *ShowWindow*.  "For GUI processes, the first time ShowWindow is called, its nCmdShow parameter is ignored "

Comment: If it helps any, I remember that STARTF_USEPOSITION and STARTF_USESIZE were a combination that I tried, but without effect. Notepad popped up in the normal place. I remember using them because I had to look up their meaning on the net.

Comment: @BenVoigt  -yes, `wShowWindow` if force used. but size and position - no. question was about this

Answer (score 1):

Your **entire** `STARTUPINFO` structure is being ignored, since you did not set the `cb` member correctly.  I am a bit surprised that `CreateProcess` is not failing outright with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

[image]

Comment: It's often the case that there's no size check for fields which have existed in a structure since day 0, since they'll "always" be in there. The size is just checked when accessing fields that were added to the structure later.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: It's also a sanity check, to make sure you aren't passing `STARTUPINFOW` to `CreateProcessA`, or 32-bit `STARTUPINFOW` to 64-bit `CreateProcessW`.